# SP GridView Filtering in share point 2010

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, spgridview

I have sp grid view in my application page, I am binding some data to the sp grid vie, now I want to apply filtering for this grid. I am googling on this one since 2 days, I am unable to get the exact link to my question. Please any suggest me some links.

Here the grid view binding code

```
protected void BindToDataTable()
        {
            string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
            using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList oListSCat = oWeb.Lists["listHelpDesk"];
                    SPListItemCollection olistItemColl = oListSCat.Items;
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Functional Area"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("FunctionalArea");
                    }
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Category"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Category");
                    }
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("SubCategory"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("SubCategory");
                    }
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Tier"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Tier");
                    }
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Region"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Region");
                    }
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Subject"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
                    }
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Description"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Description");
                    }
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Attachments"))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("Attachments");
                    }
                    foreach (SPListItem listItem in olistItemColl)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        string fncArea = listItem["Functional Area"].ToString();
                        dr["FunctionalArea"] = fncArea.Split('#')[1];
                        string cat = listItem["Category"].ToString();
                        dr["Category"] = cat.Split('#')[1];
                        string scat = listItem["Subcategory"].ToString();
                        dr["SubCategory"] = scat.Split('#')[1];
                        string tier = listItem["Tier"].ToString();
                        dr["Tier"] = tier.Split('#')[1];
                        string region = listItem["Region"].ToString();
                        dr["Region"] = region.Split('#')[1];
                        dr["Subject"] = listItem["Subject"].ToString();
                        dr["Description"] = listItem["Description"].ToString();
                        dr["Attachments"] = "Download link";
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                    }
                    ViewState["dt"] = dt; 
                    spgrdView.PagerTemplate = null;
                    //spgrdView.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }


 public void BindToGridFromSession()
        {
            spgrdView.PagerTemplate = null;
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
            spgrdView.DataSource = dt;
            spgrdView.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code,

```
oGrid.AllowFiltering = true;
oGrid.FilterDataFields = "Title"; //tells the SPGridView what columns we want to be able to  filter on.
oGrid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyName = "FilterExpression";
oGrid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat = "{1} like '{0}'"; //property provides the format for our filter expression in a SQL-like syntax.
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for filter implementation in SPGrid

http://reversealchemy.nl/building-a-spgridview-control-part-2-filtering/