# SPGridView Filtering & Sorting With DataTable

Tags: spgridview, datatable

I need a help filtering and sorting SPGridView based on DataTable, from the articles I've seen online, they use ObjectDataSource and so on, but I have the Grid binded directly to DataTable, is there any tutorial on how to implement the filtering or the sorting in this case? I've tried a lot and now working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Filtering**

```
oGrid.AllowFiltering = true;
oGrid.FilterDataFields = "Title"; //tells the SPGridView what columns we want to be able to  filter on.
oGrid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyName = "FilterExpression";
oGrid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat = "{1} like '{0}'"; //property provides the format for our filter expression in a SQL-like syntax.
```

**Sorting**

```
oGrid.AllowSorting = true;
oGrid.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(oGrid_Sorting);
void oGrid_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    // Call bind datatable function
    BindData();
}

// Also make sure when you are adding the columns you should define SortExpression
BoundField colTitle = new BoundField();
colTitle.DataField = "Title";
colTitle.HeaderText = "Title";
colTitle.SortExpression = "Title";
this.oGrid.Columns.Add(colTitle);
```

**References**

[SP GridView Filtering in share point 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76007/sp-gridview-filtering-in-share-point-2010)

[SPGridView All - Grouping, Paging, Filtering, Sorting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/91ed2bbf-b232-4fe2-94ad-1e3371d0b3e1/spgridview-all-grouping-paging-filtering-sorting?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

[Creation of a SPGridview Webpart having Pagination, Sorting, Filtering Functionalities in Sharepoint Site in Step by Step Manner](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35536/Creation-of-a-SPGridview-Webpart-having-Pagination)

Comment: Hi Arsalan, thanks for your answer, putting the code in you posted for the filter will only display the filter UI, but the filter functionality won't be there, I have only data table connected directly to spgridview, I don't have objectdatasource as stated in my question, but the articles you mentioned they all lead to solutions with ObjectDataSource, is it required for the SPGridView?

Comment: You can use existing table as ObjectDataSource, since ODS only fires one of the Server-side methods to get the data sources.. You can use it easily..

Comment: OK, but is it required for the SPGridView to work? or I can bind it directly to it. Because I've tried the method you sent above for filtering, it shows the filter, but it's disabled, you can't really filter, and on sort it will give error on post back.

Comment: Not sure if that is necessary.. but it seems like it is..